# What do we mean by Sanity Check in Salesforce Change Set Development Model?

Tags: change-set

I was going through one of the modules on Trailhead (link given below), where it was mentioned about Sanity Check. I am not a tester and hence don't have any idea about Sanity Check. I have searched about it on Google but I am unable to get the meaning.

Can anyone please explain the meaning of a Sanity check, in the process of Change Set Development model?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/declarative-change-set-development/test-in-the-integration-environment-and-deploy-changes?trailmix_creator_id=strailhead&trailmix_slug=prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-app-builder-credential

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the Trailhead carefully, they use lowercase `sanity check` indicating this is merely a human inspection of the inputs and outputs of the change set process

- Did all the metadata that was changed in the development process make it into the change set? (The fields, the permissions, the automations, etc.)
- After deployment, does the system pass a "smoke test" to verify that the changes you expected to occur actually occurred (basically, another verification that you included all the metadata in the change set)

Classic examples of why one does a sanity check are to make sure the permissions (FLS, CRUD) got deployed along with the underlying objects. When I was using change sets, I often forgot to include Visualforce page permissions or invocable Apex permissions - I had skipped the sanity check :-(

As you get more into devops, consider other deployment solutions besides change sets that are based around source version control and also look into vendor and open source solutions that automate a lot of the work for you.

Comment: Thank you so so much, now it makes sense to me. Thanks once again for taking so much pain. I am really grateful.